# Using mercurial why would I ever want to merge without committing?

Tags: version-control, mercurial, merge

Perhaps I'm biased from years of `svn` but why would I ever want to merge with a different branch then make some changes before committing. The `hg` output itself suggests otherwise:

```
(branch merge, don't forget to commit)
```

Dear `hg`, then why didn't you just do it for me?

Comment: I'm not mercurial expert, but probably it assumes that merge might require some manual adjustments, and it does not want to create commit with autogenerated incorrect merge.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because a merge operation is not guaranteed to produce correct output (automatic merges can use bad heuristics for how to deal with conflicts, manual merges can suffer from human error). Usually, what you will do is the following:

1. Merge.
2. Build.
3. Test.
4. If the test failed, fix the issue, go back to 2.
5. Commit.

Answer (score 1):

Mercurial does **not** suggests otherwise, it 's just reminder: "All merge-related changes stored only on Working Dir, commit results into repository for permanent storing" and doesn't prohibit you to make some additional changes in code before commit.

But separation of tasks (merge and not-related to merge changes - i.e changes not initiated by merge-conflicts) into separate changesets is good idea anyway